# PHP: Find last occurrence in string

Tags: php, html, string, str-replace

I am trying to drop the last vowel in a string. For example:

```
$string = 'This is a string of words.';

$vowels = array('a','e','i','o','u');

if (in_array($string, $vowels)) {

    // $newstring = '' // Drop last vowel.

}

echo $newstring; // Should echo 'This is a string of wrds.';
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: A generic answer to the question in your title is the use of `strrpos`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a regular expression we could do it:

```
$str = 'This is a string of words.';
echo preg_replace('/([aeiou]{1})([^aeiou]*)$/i', '$2', $str);
//output: This is a string of wrds.
```

Explaining a bit more the regular expression:

- $ <- the end of the phrase
- ([aeiou]{1}) <- looks for one vowel
- ([^aeiou]*) looks for any that is not a vowel

Comment: can you explain the regular expression ? .Will be helpful for many .I am the guy who posted 8 line answer to this question . :p

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer, it seems to work, but could you please explain the expression?

Comment: Adding explanation in the answer @JohnRobinson

Comment: you can safely remove `(.*)` and `$1` from regex and replacement string resp.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works

```
$string = 'This is a string of words.';

$words = explode(" ", $string);

$lastword = array_pop($words);

$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", " ");
$newlastword = str_replace($vowels, "", $lastword);

$newstring='';
foreach ($words as $value) {
    $newstring=$newstring.' '.$value;
}
$newstring=$newstring.' '.$newlastword;
echo $newstring;
```

Comment: `$string = 'This is a string of words with multiple vowels.';`

Comment: `+` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: `$newlastword` is not used

Comment: It won't work if the last word doesn't contain any wovel btw.

Comment: now it works .@malet it works because nothing will be replaced

Comment: The goal is to remove the last vowel, not to display nothing

Comment: the code only removes the vowels .if the last word doesn't have a vowel the last word does not change

Comment: Yeah, but you won't remove any vowel from any word : "This nz nznz znznz." should become "Ths nz nznz znznz."